# subprocess.run execute in background like Popen

Tags: python, subprocess

The `subprocess` docs say

> The recommended approach to invoking subprocesses is to use the run() function for all use cases it can handle.

[`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) executes in the foreground, waiting for the subprocess to exit. `subprocess.Popen` executes in the background, immediately returning a Popen object. Can I make `subprocess.run` immediately return a Popen object running in the background?

```
In [3]: subprocess.Popen(['sleep', '10'])                                       
# Immediately
Out[3]: <subprocess.Popen object at 0x7f70b38609b0>

In [4]: subprocess.run(['sleep', '10'])                                         
# 10 seconds later
Out[4]: CompletedProcess(args=['sleep', '10'], returncode=0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The docs for `run` specifically call out that it waits:

> Run the command described by args. Wait for command to complete, then
>   return a CompletedProcess instance.

It was introduced in Python 3.5 as a simplification of Popen/communicate for use cases where waiting for the process to finish is acceptable.